# popBackStack causes calling oncreateView of fragment again and again

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, back-stack, fragmentmanager

I have 3 fragment A, B,C.I wrote piece of code for replacing them and maintaining backstack:

```
 public void addFragment(Fragment fragmentToAdd, String fragmentTag) {
        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment activeFragment = getActiveFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        if (null != activeFragment) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(activeFragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_child_activity, fragmentToAdd,
                fragmentTag);

       if (supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Here in this piece of code

```
if (supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
    supportFragmentManager.popBackStack();
}
```

I using for pop the latest fragment if stack length is more than 1. Now due to this when length is going greater than 1 than it is calling onCreate view again and again.
Like :

1. open A.
2. open B.
3. open C.**(In case of open C. onCreateView of A is called. )**

Why I am getting such kind of behavior ? When I am removing that italic code than it is not happening.

Comment: Can you give more details about what are you trying to achieve by using that code?

Comment: @Szymon I want to switch between my fragments which are present in drawer and maintain back stack length 1.

Comment: have you found any soloution of this problem?

Answer (score 12):

Than behavior is normal, coming from the backstack transaction, as the docs say. The backstack never saves Fragments, it just saves the transaction

[image]

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html

What I do, I am not sure if, is it the best way but
when I want to clear all the transactions I do this

1) INSIDE YOUR ACTIVITY check if is there any transactions in the back stack,
   and add a flag inside your fragment, in your case is A

```
       int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

       if(backStackCount > 0) {
           Transactions.MUST_DETACH_FROM_BACKSTACK = true;
           getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
       }
```

2) Inside your fragment A, get the flag and Remove the fragment `onCreateView` and return null like this

```
public class Transactions extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

public static boolean MUST_DETACH_FROM_BACKSTACK = false;

public Transactions() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("FRAGMENT", "onCreateView "+MUST_DETACH_FROM_BACKSTACK);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if (MUST_DETACH_FROM_BACKSTACK) {
        MUST_DETACH_FROM_BACKSTACK = false;
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
        return null;
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transactions, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    Log.i("FRAGMENT", "onViewCreated");
    if(view != null){

        Log.i("FRAGMENT", "ThreadStarted");
        startThread(view);
    }
}
```

BUT BE CAREFULL I Get onResume() Called after the

```
OnCreateView()
```

even with  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();

So if you have any conde onResume method you should handle it properly

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by inheriting (1) all fragments from my custom BaseFragment (2).
In this BaseFragment I created a variable: public static boolean removing; (3)
and set it to true (4) before calling popBackStackImmediate() and reset it to false after that. (5)
In the BaseFragment-childs I check the variable. (6)

Example-Code

Activity-class

```
    BaseFragment.removing = true; //(4)
    //pop all fragments
    while(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    }
    BaseFragment.removing = false; //(5)
```

BaseFragment (2)

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment{
   public static boolean removing = false; //(3)
}
```

Fragment-Child

```
public class fragment extends BaseFragment{ //(1)
  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      if(!removing){ // (6)
          //your code
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Remember the life cycle of a `fragment`. By the time we get back to this, it will start from `oncreateView()` always. But we can still save data that we will then process in the oncreated to fill our view. for you you can do that:

> Main-activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment2.myListener {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment1 fragment1 = Fragment1.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment1, Fragment1.TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Fragment1.TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    Log.e(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void bindCount(int newCount) {
    ((Fragment1)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Fragment1.TAG)).setCount(newCount);
}
```

}

> Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
public static final String TAG = "fragment1";
private static final String SAVE_COUNT = "save_count";

private int count;

public Fragment1() {
}

public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
    Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        count = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVE_COUNT);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);


    Button goToButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    goToButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment2 fragment2 = Fragment2.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment2, Fragment2.TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Fragment2.TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public  void setCount(int newCount){
    count = newCount;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.e(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: ");
    outState.putInt(SAVE_COUNT, count);
}
```

}

> Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
public static final String TAG = "fragment2";

public Fragment2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static Fragment2 newInstance() {
    Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();

    return fragment;
}

myListener listener;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false);
    //Here I am just modifying a value that wants to send to fragment1
    listener.bindCount(45);//newCount

    return view;
}

public interface myListener{
    void bindCount(int newCount);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //initialice listener
    listener = (myListener) getActivity();
}
```

}

So ... For the communication between `fragments` we will need your container `activity`, through interface. As we can see, Fragment2 has an `interface` that implements its `activity` and when it is executed, it calls a method where we change the count value in `fragment1`, which is stored in `onSaveInstanceState`, so we can resume any modification that occurs even when `oncreateview` is executed again. this can be used for many other data such as `arraylist, string, float, long, object,` etc.

sorry my "english"!!!!!