# Fragment popbackstack is calling the previous fragment oncreateview instead on onstart. How to make it call onStart?

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack

Am Replacing Fragment B on top of Fragment A. Then Some time Later am calling popBackStack();. It's Pop the current fragment B from stack. Then Fragment A's OncreateView is getting called. I am not sure When the Fragment A get's detached from an activity. why it's calling fragment onCreateView again.  For my case I want to call the Framgent A's OnStart Method instead of calling onCreateView method. 
Please help me on this.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question is answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35163908/5577745